# How to create a moving object(Dot) on my Jframe (Netbeans)?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Hi guys thanks for your answers ahead of time. I am wondering how i would go about creating a dot and making that dot move across my jFrame. This Dot would only be able to move on a picture of a grid in my jFrame upon keystroke. If anyone can post some code (as example for me to refer to) as to how to create the "dot/point" and how to make this dot move across my jFrame on keystroke i would greatly appreciate it. thanks :)

Comment: Well me and my brother are new to netbeans and to writing code so we dont know where we would start so no we haven't tried anything. :/

Comment: Then look it up. StackOverflow is for people who have tried something and need help. However I can provide a couple of pointers...

Comment: *" If anyone can post some code"* That's not how this really works and there are plenty of examples already available on SO.  Maybe break your requirements down a little so you can find each aspect separately

Comment: Start by taking a look at [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), [Custom painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for starters

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer again for the help and thanks others ill look more into my topic more before i ask a question next time >:D. thanks for links

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a JFrame, you need to add a JPanel to it and put your rendering code in the `repaint()` method of the JPanel.

I would suggest you look at [this](https://github.com/anubiann00b/JFrameExample) example of how to use a JFrame properly.

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private MyJPanel frame;

    public MyJFrame() {
        super();
        frame = new MyJPanel();
        add(frame);
        pack();
        addKeyListener(this);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyJFrame window = new MyJFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("Test");
    }

    @Override
    public void repaint() {
        super.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        frame.keyPressed(e);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

Here is the `MyJPanel` class:

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public MyJPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(x,y,1,1);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();

        switch (k) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                x++;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                x--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                y--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                y++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Using `KeyListener` is optional but allows you to get keyboard input.

I know that this is long and not very direct, but I hope you can learn something from this code. If you have any other questions, feel free to comment, and I'll help you out as best I can.

MyJFrame needs to import:

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
java.awt.event.KeyListener;
javax.swing.JFrame;
```

MyJPanel needs to import:

```
java.awt.Color;
java.awt.Dimension;
java.awt.Graphics;
java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
javax.swing.JPanel;
```

Comment: Do i need to import any packages for this I'm getting errors on @Overide and keylistener.

Comment: Yes you do, I didn't include it though. It's in the Github repo, lemme find it...

Comment: 1) Swing components should override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)`, and should firstly call the `super` method. 2)  The `repaint()` method override is pointless.  3) `update(Graphics g)` Why is the code doing anything to this method? 4) Rather than setting a preferred size to the custom painted panel, it is considered better to override the default method.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think I understand the gist of what you're saying, but can you elaborate further?

Comment: *"but can you elaborate further?"*  Sure I can, but I don't intend writing a novel on the matter.  So what *specifically* are you having trouble understanding?  Can *you* elaborate further?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'll get back to you after I implement some of your suggestions :)